# Linear Independence in R^n

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have two distinct, non-parallel vectors in  $\Bbb R^{n} $, must they be linearly independent?
Is there a good generalised argument for why this should be so?

Comment: If $v$ and $w$ are two such vectors, what does it mean for them to be non-parallel?

Comment: by parallel I mean that v = kw where k is scalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the independence of vectors $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ you have to determine if there exists nontrivial (not all zero) solution of equation

$\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2v_2 + ... + \alpha_nv_n = 0$    (1)

If it exists then vectors are not independent.

If there are only two vectors, and they  are not parallel then there doesn't exist any $k\neq0$ such that

$v_1 = kv_2$

thus

$v_1 - kv_2 \neq0$ for all $k$.

But the condition (1) in case of just two vectors boils down to $v_1 + \alpha v_2 =0$ with $\alpha = \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}$. Therefore these vectors must be independent.

Answer (score 2):

If $av+bw=0$ with $a\neq 0$ then $v=-\frac baw$ and $v,w$ are parallel. Simlilarly if $b\neq0$ then $w=-\frac abv$. Linear dependence of $v,w$ would mean that at least one of the two holds (most probably both).

Comment: So suppose I had (a, b, c, d) and (a+1, b, c, d). Would they be linearly independent or not?

Comment: @Bye_World The independence of $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(a+1,b,c,d)$ depends more on $b,c,d$ than it does on $a$.

Comment: @Bye_World Yeah, but note that there is one choice of $b,c,d$ that makes these vectors linearly dependent...

Comment: @ThanksABundle: I dont quite understand your question. You'r talking about specific vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ (which is not quite what the original question was about)?